# if/else/fi && syntax error

Tags: shell

I'm trying to chain an additional command after an if/else/fi, but I'm getting a syntax error.

Here's what I've got:

```
mkdir -p storage/app storage/framework/cache storage/framework/sessions storage/framework/views storage/logs bootstrap/cache \
&& if [ "$ENV" = "production" ] ; then \
    composer install \
; else \
    composer install --no-suggest --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts --no-dev --no-cache \
fi ; \
&& chown -R 33:33 . && chmod -R a-sx,ug=rwX,o=rX . && chmod ug+x ./artisan
```

Error is

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected

Is there a way I can chain this?

It's going into a Dockerfile so I'm trying to minimize the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

A command can not start with `&&`, which is what you have just before the  `chown` command.

That command is `&& chown ...` because of the preceding `;`.

Without the `;`, the `chown` would be executed depending on the exit status of the `if` compound command.

Written without most of the rather confusing line continuations, your (corrected) code would look like

```
mkdir -p storage/app storage/framework/cache storage/framework/sessions \
         storage/framework/views storage/logs bootstrap/cache &&
if [ "$environment" = "production" ]; then
    composer install
else
    composer install --no-suggest --optimize-autoloader \
        --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts --no-dev --no-cache
fi &&
chown -R 33:33 . &&
chmod -R a-sx,ug=rwX,o=rX . &&
chmod ug+x ./artisan
```

Note also my change of `$ENV` to `$environment`.  The `ENV` variable may, depending on the shell, be used by the shell to execute (source) a separate file before running another script.  In general, use lower-case variable names to avoid accidentally using important shell or environment variables.

Comment: I know `set -e` has its problems, but I might consider using it here instead of a long `&&` chain